# How do I open the file browser? ( Android SDK)

Tags: android, file, browser, sdk

How do I open the file browser (like in the File Manager) with Android SDK?
Is there some Intent or something else to do so?

Comment: @user727194: There is no "file browser" in Android.

Comment: You should have accepted this answer

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, there is no built in way to do that.  You can try using the [OI FileManager](http://openintents.org/en/filemanager) - it is quite nice but the user is required to install the app to use it.

There's also a good example of how to make your own [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/).