# How to open directory by default app android

Tags: android, android-intent

Please help me about this question.
I know how to open a file by default app like this :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = ExternalStorageHelper.getFileFromName(fileName);
    MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
    String ext =fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
    String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
    if(type != null){
        if(mime.hasMimeType(type)){
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),type);
            containActivity.startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }else{
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(containActivity, R.string.download_open_file_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(containActivity, R.string.download_open_file_error_message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
    }
```

but I can't find out how to open a folder by default app.
From this code how can I determine to MimeTypeMap fileName is a Directory.

I am really need it now, please help me :)

Comment: did you mean to list the folder details ?

Comment: I mean example : I have folder like : sdcard/abc/ 
Now I want to open this folder in default app like file manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, there is no built in way to do that. You can try using
>   the OI FileManager - it is quite nice but the user is required to
>   install the app to use it.
>
> There's also a good example of how to make your own here.

[How do I open the file browser? ( Android SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803787/how-do-i-open-the-file-browser-android-sdk)